# Extract a single tag from an xml file from a shell script

Tags: xml, bash

I have a bunch of xml files that I would like to extract a single tag from and save to a text file. i.e., how can I turn

manifest.xml:

```
<package>
        <description brief="Moving Horizon Estimator for the kite carousel">

    dynamicMHE - MHE for the kite carousel, with dynamic model

        </description>
        <author>rsetrsntrstn</author>
        <license>LGPL</license>
        <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
        <url>TODO</url>

        <!-- RTT & OCL integration -->
        <depend package="rtt_rosnode"/>
        <depend package="rtt_std_msgs"/>
        <depend package="rtt_rosnode"/>

        <!-- RTT & OCL -->
        <depend package="rtt"/>
        <depend package="ocl"/>

</package>
```

into

readme.txt:

```
dynamicMHE - MHE for the kite carousel, with dynamic model
```

in a simple way from a shell script.  I don't want to have to learn anything about fancy xml parsers; the whole point of this exercise is to excise all of the xml from our codebase.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out from looking at other questions:

> ```
> xmlstarlet sel -t -v //description manifest.xml > readme.txt
> ```

Note: the stuff following the // is NOT a comment of any kind; xmlstarlet just has very weird syntax.

Comment: The thing that screwed me up with xmlstarlet command at first was the weird syntax following the // stuff, which looks like a comment to me, and even stack overflow, apparently.

Comment: It's more like the `//` in `http://`, if that helps at all, although it doesn't quite mean the same thing. Like URLs and filepaths, `/` means "go down one level". However, `//` means "go down as many levels as you need to find what follows, so `//description` is something like `description || /description || //description || /// description...`

Comment: @DrewWagner xmlstarlet uses xpath expressions, just like xmllint.

Answer (score 0):

The [xmllint](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_xmllint.htm) can be used to run an [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expresson to extract information from any part of the XML file:

```
xmllint --xpath "string(/package/description)" manifest.xml > readme.txt
```